# Need help finding a story about sunglasses that grant wishes

Tags: story-identification

The story is about a boy who finds a pair of sunglasses at the top of a mountain or hill. At one point a wish is made to have a Lamborghini Countach. When the sunglasses become damaged, they sap electricity from the nearest source and are repaired.

Other details include the following:

- A large, growing, storm appears at some point in the book.
- The book ends shortly after a wish is made that makes it as if the events never happened, and the boy ends up back at the top of the mountain or hill, but he doesn't grab the sunglasses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Eyes of Kid Midas](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Eyes_of_Kid_Midas.html?id=4tfAnuoa37EC), by Neal Shusterman.

Comment: that seems to be it. had to find an original publication date, and it all seems to match what i remember. thanks